# Index of numpy array is None

Tags: python, numpy

For example, a matrix X

```
>>> X
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5, -1,  7,  8,  9]])
```

what is the meaning of 
`>>> X[None,:]`

```
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
        [ 5, -1,  7,  8,  9]]])
```

So, it changes the dimension of the matrix respect to the None axis? Am I right? Thanks for any help.

Comment: That's not a list. That's a NumPy array.

Comment: sorry for my mistake. It is a numpy array.

Comment: It adds a dimension. `X` is 2d (2,5); `X[None, :, :]` is 3d (1,2,5).